# Generar Archivo Objeto en Dev-C++ sin trabajar por proyectos

Tags: archivo, objeto, dev-c++, compilador, compilacion

Mi pregunta es si se puede generar un Archivo Objeto en Dev-C++ al trabajar **con un único archivo independiente**, no con un proyecto. De hecho, cuando trabajo con un proyecto sí he conseguido hacerlo, pero para un archivo suelto no lo he conseguido revisando todas las opciones del compilador. No sé si será posible o no. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar? Muchas gracias.

Saludos

Comment: No sé de Dev-C++ pero seguramente puedas utilizar el compilador desde el terminal. Así no necesitas depender del IDE.

Comment: Gracias. En caso de que necesite hacerlo con el IDE, ¿habría alguna forma? ¿Alguien la sabe?